# Contrast enhancement of the image

Tags: image, matlab, contrast

I am writing the code for a section of the paper shown in the [image showing the alogrithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOGKF.jpg). The section is regarding the contrast enhancement of the image for improving the blurriness. please guide whether it is right!!
The code written in Matlab is as follows.

```
clear all
close all
I=imread('105.jpg');
figure,imshow(I);
Ir=I(:,:,1);
Ig=I(:,:,2);
Ib=I(:,:,3);
In=(Ir+Ig+Ib)/3;
[r,c]=size(In)
T1=30;
T2=50;
for i=2:r-1
   for j=1:c
      if((In(i+1,j)-In(i-1,j))>T1)
         Ir(i+1,j)=Ir(i+1,j)+T2;
         Ir(i-1,j)=Ir(i-1,j)-T2;
         Ig(i+1,j)=Ig(i+1,j)+T2;
         Ig(i-1,j)=Ig(i-1,j)-T2;
         Ib(i+1,j)=Ib(i+1,j)+T2;
         Ib(i-1,j)=Ib(i-1,j)-T2;
      end
   end
end
Iresult(:,:,1)=Ir(:,:,1);
Iresult(:,:,2)=Ig(:,:,1);
Iresult(:,:,3)=Ib(:,:,1);
grayImg=(Iresult);
figure, imshow(grayImg);
```

I request to please guide me whether the code is written is correct or not as per algorithm is shown in the image.
The image showing the algorithm is [image showing contrast enhancement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j5SQ.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried your code to improve the contrast of an image?

Comment: Yes I m trying to to remove blurness of the I image so that it can be further pass on to mser detection process...it will be used in detection of text regions

Comment: The attached image shows the algorithm ..the code is to implemented on the basis of the given algorithm attached ...

Comment: And does your code works, based on a your sample images?

Comment: Yes it is working but desried results are not coming as per the research paper

Comment: Have you tried it with the same images as the research paper?

Comment: Yes the images used in dataset is from icdar 2011. I HV used them..

Comment: The only issue I m concerned is that code I HV written is matching with algorithm or not..

Comment: The paper says if on original image this algorithm is applied then blurness is removed and there for letters in the image will be separated, and therefore text detection precision will increase. So for that algorithm should be implemented correctly. So it is required to see whether code is correct or not. It says to get intensity image in hsi mode..that is not understood

Comment: What you ask is not an easy task, error prone and requires a lot of specific knowledge about your problem. So, you will probably not find an answer here. Therefore, I suggested you to validate it yourself by using sample images and looking at the result.

Comment: It is reference to the paper titled scene text detection via stroke width .http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.700.8773&rep=rep1&type=pdf  I just want to know whether the code matches the algorithm or not.  So please have a look once again. Thanks sir